# Common text data sets in form of panel data

Tags: data-request, nlp, text

I want to test machine learning tasks on time-divided textual data set. For this purpose, I want to use a common text data set which is already validated and "good" for use. I already found a Web of Science data set from this source:

> K. Kowsari, D. E. Brown, M. Heidarysafa, K. Jafari Meimandi, M. S.
>   Gerber and L. E. Barnes, "HDLTex: Hierarchical Deep Learning for Text
>   Classification", 2017 16th IEEE International Conference on Machine
>   Learning and Applications (ICMLA), pp. 364-371. doi:
>   10.1109/ICMLA.2017.0-134

Unfortunately, the data set does not include data about the time of the publications, which I really need for my algorithms. Can anyone recommend a common textual data set for me which is divided into time windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answer by @Erwan, I came across

- [nlp-datasets](https://github.com/niderhoff/nlp-datasets), collected by Nicolas Iderhoff;
- [Awesome Public Datasets](https://github.com/awesomedata/awesome-public-datasets#naturallanguage), collected by AwesomeData.

Both are curated lists of text datasets for NLP tasks.  A few datasets that may fit your requirement of temporal variation:

- [Cheng-Caverlee-Lee September 2009 - January 2010 Twitter Scrape](https://archive.org/details/twitter_cikm_2010): Timestamped tweets (3,844,612 training, 5,156,047 testing) for NLP geolocation task.  See paper [here](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1871535).
- [NIPS2015 Papers (version 2) [Kaggle]](https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/nips-2015-papers/version/2): full text of all NIPS2015 papers
- Reddit comments: [I have every publicly available Reddit comment for research. ~ 1.7 billion comments @ 250 GB compressed. Any interest in this?](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/3bxlg7/i_have_every_publicly_available_reddit_comment/), Reddit, July 2015;
- YouTube videos: [1.7 millions Youtube videos' description](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/3gegdz/17_millions_youtube_videos_description/) on Reddit, August 2015.

Since you're looking for datasets that have been used in previous NLP studies, I suggest searching these lists for data from Kaggle competitions or academic papers.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what kind of text you're looking for. I can think of the following three sources for text data with years of publication:

- [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/) is a repository containing 60,000 books in the public domain. It includes a lot of literature classics. I don't think the original publication date is included but for many books it's not to hard to retrieve it from Wikipedia.
- [Google NGrams](https://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) is a massive collection of n-grams extracted from one million books. Each n-gram is provided with the year of the book it comes from, but there is no full text available.
- [Medline and/or PubMed Central](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/medline.html) abstracts (around 20 millions) and/or full papers (around 2 millions) from scientific biomedical articles. The year of publication is included in the metadata.